# Displays tabs in Firefox 3.6 across multiple rows?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, layout

After upgrading to Firefox 3.6, I noticed that there no longer seems to be a way to have tabs all displayed in several rows when there are too many to fit in the window:

[image]

I find it very inconvenient to have to click on the down arrow at the far-right side to go through the list of open tabs.

The TabMixPlus add-on is incompatible with ReloadEvery 3.6.2, so that's not a good solution either.

Does someone know if it's possible to either configure FireFox 3.6 to go back to the previous way of displaying multiple tabs, or if there's an add-on that's compatible with ReloadEvery that would do the trick?

---

**Edit**: The solution if you need support for both multiple-row tabs + being able to reload one of the tabs automatically every so often, is to just use [TabMixPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122), which does both and is compatible with Firefox 3.6.

Comment: TabMixPlus is also able to reload tabs automatically. Right click on tab and select "Reload tab every...". Is this not what you want?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know TabMixPlus could be told to reload a given tab/document every so often. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [TooManyTabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9429) add-on.

> TooManyTabs allows you to store as many tabs as you like by adding
>   extra rows in the Firefox! It saves your browser's space and memory as
>   idle tabs are put aside. The extra rows also help to better prioritize
>   and visualize your tabs.

Comment: Unfortunately, TooManyTabs [does not work with Firefox Quantum](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toomanytabs-saves-your-memory/), so this answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [TabKit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5447) ? also I think that you'll have to take a look at [this solution](https://forums.addons.mozilla.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=789&p=1937). Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, Tabkit does not work with Firefox Quantum, so this answer is now out of date.  Your link to "this solution" leads to Error 404.